# Select(DropDownListFor) с произвольным вводом текста

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mvc

Пытаюсь сделать **select** для реквизита **Title** с возможностью выбора варианта или с вводом произвольного значения. 
Создал простую модель:

```
 public class Email
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Message { get; set; }
    }
```

отображаю ее на вьюхе:

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Title , "Title")
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Title, new SelectList(new string[] { "Title 1", "Title 2", "Title 3"}))
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Message , "Message")
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Message)
```

собственно с выбором варианта все нормально, но ума не приложу как задать произвольный текст для этого поля, т.к. **select** запрещает ввод значений не из списка выбора.

Собственно вопрос: как сделать Select(DropDownListFor) с возможностью ввода произвольного значения?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

То, что вы ищете, называется "autocomplete dropdownlist". [Вот](http://instinctcoder.com/asp-net-mvc-4-jquery-autocomplete-dropdownlist/), например, одна из реализаций для asp.net MVC с обычным jQuery, который входит в проект MVC по умолчанию.